# how can i ng-repeat on two arrays AngularJs Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have i side menu with accordion under menu.

i populate those under menus with my controller so i did this :

controller.js :

```
$scope.groupsR = [];
for (var t=0; t<1; t++) {
  $scope.groupsR[t] = {
    name: "Reporting",
    titles: [],
    urls: []
  };
  for (var u=0; u<2; u++) {
    switch (u){
      case 0 : $scope.groupsR[t].titles.push("Pilotage Commercial");
               $scope.groupsR[t].urls.push("pilotageCommercial");
        break;
      case 1 : $scope.groupsR[t].titles.push("Pilotage BackOffice");
               $scope.groupsR[t].urls.push("pilotageBackOffice");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

menu.html :

```
<ion-item class="item-accordion"
                ng-repeat="title in groupR.titles"
                ng-repeat = "url in groupR.urls"
                ng-show="isGroupShown(groupR)"
                ui-sref="menu.{{url}}"
                menu-close="">
        {{title}}
</ion-item>
```

the under menu appear with the correct title but the url are wrong ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the index from the first `ng-repeat`:

```
{{ groupR.urls[$index] }}
```

---

### Edit: Better yet:

```
switch (u){
    case 0: angular.extend($scope.groupsR[t], {
        title: "Pilotage Commercial",
        url: "pilotageCommercial"
    });
    break;
    case 1: angular.extend($scope.groupsR[t], {
        title: "Pilotage BackOffice",
        url: "pilotageBackOffice"
    });
    break;
}
```

with:

```
<ion-item class="item-accordion"
    ng-repeat="item in groupR"
    ng-show="isGroupShown(groupR)"
    ui-sref="menu.{{item.url}}"
    menu-close="">
    {{item.title}}
</ion-item>
```

This also works when you use filtering or sorting, because that will mess with the `$index` variable

Comment: @anisscherkaoui please also check my edit, this is even better for when you use filters or ordering

Comment: Error: $scope.groupsR[t].push is not a function. (In '$scope.groupsR[t].push({
            title: "Pilotage Commercial",
            url: "pilotageCommercial"
          })', '$scope.groupsR[t].push' is undefined)

Comment: no problem with this {{ groupR.urls[$index] }} it works perfectly ^^

Comment: Okay, but it may not work if you add more functionality